# Tricky makefile syntax with quotes

Tags: syntax, makefile, quotes

I have the following start on a makefile rule (thanks to help from others), but it doesn't quite work yet:

```
test_svn_version:
    @if [ $$(svn --version --quiet \ 
            perl -ne '@a=split(/\./); \
                      print $$a[0]*10000 + $$a[1]*100 + $$a[2]') \
          -lt 10600 ]; \
    then \
        echo >&2 "Svn version $$(svn --version --quiet) too old; upgrade to v1.6";
        false; \
    fi
```

It seems the single quote in the conditional is unmatched.

Please help correct the syntax.  I've tried many variants, but none seem correct.

Thanks.

-William

Comment: The example is missing a pipe (|) after the svn command and a backslash after the echo. Are these just typos in the example, or are they missing from the source too?

Comment: Often its easier to just use long lines, and an editor that can deal with it, instead of putting in lots of backslashes.  I would still put the perl command on a line by itself, though.  Or get the svn version into a Make variable, and do more logic in make.  And there are tools for comparing version numbers.  You don't have to parse the version number and add it up into an integer...  Although that looks simple enough in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a pipe `|` between svn and perl, and you're missing a backslash `\` after the echo. This works for me:

```
test_svn_version:
    @if [ $$(svn --version --quiet | \
             perl -ne '@a=split(/\./); \
                       print $$a[0]*10000 + $$a[1]*100 + $$a[2]') \
          -lt 10600 ]; \
    then \
        echo >&2 "Svn version $$(svn --version --quiet) too old; upgrade to v1.6"; \
        false; \
    fi
```